# Question on scala compiler syntax hacking

Tags: scala

I am looking to write a system which allows a syntax like the following:

```
a b/c
```

With a being a class, b being a specific term (not any arbitrary string) and c being an Int.

I realize you can do

```
a b c
```

which becomes

```
a.b(c)
```

However, the first syntax would be more elegant and any solution would help me expand my scala knowledge :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any of these is good enough for you...

```
a { b/c }
a ( b/c )
```

...this will do the trick:

```
trait Term { def / (n:Int):(Term,Int) = (this,n) }

case object Inc extends Term  // any other terms declared likewise
```

and then your class could support it this way:

```
class A { 
   def apply(t:(Term,Int)) = t match { 
     case (Inc,n) => n + 1 
     // further term implementations
   } 
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> val a = new A
a: A = A@1c2628

scala> a { Inc / 8 }
res28: Int = 9

scala> a ( Inc / 8 )
res29: Int = 9
```